# SVR Overfitting?

Tags: svm

My data has 3168x7 (being targets the first column). I´m trying to do SVR-RBF.

I did 10fold , and gotta better results with gamma 8.

But, when apllied to my external test set, I gotta bad results (overfit?).

So, I tried to minimize gamma, and get good results (in the test set) with 0.0625.

How this is possible ?

Why I´m getting good cross validation results, and bad test results ?

Why I´m getting worse cross validation results, and better test results ?

Thanks in advance.

Andre

Answer (score 1):

High values of $\gamma$ (low bandwidth) induce more complex models. It seems that you have a classical case of overfitting on the training set. However, cross-validation *should* pick up on this as well, since it is intended to provide good estimates of generalization performance.

Cross-validation works assuming the test set is similar to the training set. Is this the case in your application or is it possible that your test set is fundamentally different?

Comment: Marc, both training and test sets are artificially done by an simulator. What I did was, for the training, simulation of targets 1 and 5, so, for the test set, Ive simulated 3 for example. The data has the same fundamental origins.